# Broken snap system after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

Please help to install all needed packages to run snap files and integration with Store

Here is my errors:

```
snap list
2018/12/09 11:36:41.694959 main.go:162: argument "abort"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695044 main.go:162: argument "ack"'s "<файл подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695158 main.go:162: argument "tasks"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695197 main.go:162: argument "create-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695229 main.go:162: argument "create-user"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695245 main.go:162: argument "delete-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695307 main.go:162: argument "export-key"'s "<имя ключа>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695351 main.go:162: argument "find"'s "<запрос>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695383 main.go:162: argument "get"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695463 main.go:162: argument "interface"'s "<интерфейс>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695506 main.go:162: argument "known"'s "<тип подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695517 main.go:162: argument "known"'s "<фильт заголовков>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695549 main.go:162: argument "login"'s "<отослать>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695614 main.go:162: argument "prepare-image"'s "<модель подтверждения>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695626 main.go:162: argument "prepare-image"'s "<корневая директория>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695676 main.go:162: argument "services"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695714 main.go:162: argument "logs"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695738 main.go:162: argument "start"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695766 main.go:162: argument "stop"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695789 main.go:162: argument "restart"'s "<сервис>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695812 main.go:162: argument "set"'s "<конфигурационное значение>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.695856 main.go:162: argument "sign-build"'s "<имя файла>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.696189 main.go:162: argument "wait"'s "<ключ>s" should be wrapped in <>s
2018/12/09 11:36:41.696230 main.go:162: argument "watch"'s "<смена ID>s" should be wrapped in <>s
Name                  Version                    Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                  16-2.36.2+git1055.114a76a  6095  edge      canonical✓  core
core18                18                         468   edge      canonical✓  base
gnome-calculator      3.30.1                     260   stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-characters      3.30.0                     139   stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.30.0                     57    stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-4-g88bc1b2             818   stable    canonical✓  -
```

Comment: I'll strongly recommend you to come back to the site after 2 days to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to fix that but is to put locale to `/etc/default/locale` e.g.:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

check changes with cat /etc/default/locale

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

or edit bash profiale `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Snap seems to be experiencing problems under foreign languages in Ubuntu 18.10. The bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1806761).

As of now the simple workaround is:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/locale-langpack/ru/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo
```

or use `LANG=C` before any snap command